# Command 'electrum' not found

Tags: software-installation, python

I just installed (using sudo -H) electrum 3.3.8 on 18.04 LTS ubuntu and it looks like everything works:

the results of `python3 -m pip install --user Electrum-3.3.8.tar.gz[fast]` are:

```
Successfully installed Electrum-3.3.8 aiohttp-3.5.4 aiohttp-socks-0.2.2 aiorpcx-0.18.3 async-timeout-3.0.1 attrs-19.1.0 certifi-2019.6.16 chardet-3.0.4 dnspython-1.16.0 ecdsa-0.13.2 idna-2.8 idna-ssl-1.1.0 jsonrpclib-pelix-0.4.0 multidict-4.5.2 protobuf-3.9.1 pyaes-1.6.1 pycryptodomex-3.8.2 qdarkstyle-2.6.8 qrcode-6.1 setuptools-41.0.1 six-1.12.0 typing-extensions-3.7.4 yarl-1.3.0
```

I did this at `terminus@elrond:~$`
when i type electrum at the command line, however, I get this:

```
Command 'electrum' not found.
```

I'm assuming I'm in the wrong part of my file structure, but when I search, I can't find the electrum executable.  The electrum icon doesn't show on the Dash either.

Where is Electrum-3.3.8 on my computer, and how can i run electrum? Is there a specific place in the file structure where I need to install electrum?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this off topic because it's a generic Linux/ubuntu maintenance question and not specific to Bitcoin.

Comment: Agreeing with Pieter, I add the reference to a possible solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/109381/how-to-add-path-of-a-program-to-path-environment-variable

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there are things to polish with the new `.local` directory structure in Ubuntu and how applications use it.

I would recommend you to repeat the command without the `--user` parameter from the user console (If `--user` is used the dependencies are not later correctly found):

`python3 -m pip install Electrum-3.3.8.tar.gz`

It will be quick as all packages are already downloaded.

It is not compulsory, but creating a symbolic link makes things easier:

`sudo ln -s ~/.local/bin/electrum /usr/local/bin/electrum`

Then you can run electrum with:

`electrum`

Also remember that you can run electrum from any folder you choose, following the alternative instructions from electrum:

```
tar -xvf Electrum-3.3.8.tar.gz
python3 Electrum-3.3.8/run_electrum
```